# Change Latex Table Style using Sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, pandoc, pdflatex

I'm using `sphinx` to generate our company manuals. In our legacy manuals we have a certain table style, that we would like to keep.

The table style consists of tables having a header with dark green background, then there are several light-green background rows and after that several rows with a white background.

`Sphinx` generates my LaTeX input files, which are then made an PDF using PdfLatex. There is the possibility to include LaTeX specific comments right before the LaTeX table starts with `:raw-role:`.

The input RST file:

```
.. role:: raw-role(raw)
   :format: latex

:raw-role:`\firstRow`   

=== === ===
 A   B   C
=== === ===
1A   1B  1C
2A   2B  2C
3A   3B  3C
4A   4B  4C
=== === ===
```

Will be transformed into:

```
\firstRow

\noindent\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
\hline
\sphinxstylethead{\relax 
A
\unskip}\relax &\sphinxstylethead{\relax 
B
\unskip}\relax &\sphinxstylethead{\relax 
C
\unskip}\relax \\
\hline
1A
&
1B
&
1C
\\
\hline
2A
&
2B
&
2C
\\
\hline
3A
&
3B
&
3C
\\
\hline
4A
&
4B
&
4C
\\
\hline\end{tabulary}
```

I'm now in need for a command called `\firstRow` that modifies the behaviour of the `\tabulary` environment, so that the header has a dark-green background, the first row beneath has a light-green background and the remaining rows having a white background.

If everything else fails there might be still the possibility to automatically replace the contents of the cells in the RST-File using a tool like `pandoc`.
For example it might be possible to replace `1A` by `:raw-role:'\background{green}' 1A` in the RST file and then to transform it with `sphinx`.

I found it interesting that in case of the sphinx `HTML` target the problem can be very easily solved by using an adapted `style.css` containing the class `firstRow` together with a command like `.. rst-class:: firstRow`, where `firstRow` represents a table style with one light green background.

Unfortunately, the LaTeX target misses something similar to `style.css`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, LaTeX is in no way as customizable as HTML+CSS.

There might be some package providing convenient interface to colorizing the first two rows of a table, unfortunately I am not aware of one which would work with a macro like `\firstRow` before the table. The `xcolor` package provides (if loaded with option table) a `\rowcolors` command, but it does not seem to suffice. It is easy to obtain  the desired goal by manual mark-up of the LaTeX source, but it is more complicated achieving this solely using `\firstRow` macro.

I ended up with a convoluted approach, which I tested on Sphinx 1.5.3.

in `conf.py`:

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': r"""
\usepackage{colortbl}
\protected\def\sphinxstylethead {\cellcolor{green}\textsf}
"""
}
```

---

Edit: since Sphinx 1.6, `\sphinxstylethead` is deprecated and `\sphinxstyletheadfamily` [should be used instead](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/changes.html#id9). This means that the above should now be:

```
latex_elements = {
    'preamble': r"""
\usepackage{colortbl}
\protected\def\sphinxstyletheadfamily {\cellcolor{green}\sffamily}
"""
}
```

The former version works with Sphinx 1.6 but will fail with 1.7 when `\sphinxstylethead` will stopped being used by Sphinx.

---

in reST sources, something like this:

```
======  === ===
  A      B   C
======  === ===
|x| 1A   1B  1C
2A       2B  2C
3A       3B  3C
4A       4B  4C
======  === ===


.. |x| raw:: latex

       \rowcolor{blue}
```

Of course change colours to your liking. You may need to pass an option like `dvipsnames` to `xcolor` package, and then you can use things like `\rowcolor[named]{ForestGreen}`.

[image]

Sphinx 1.6 will have table templates allowing some easier customization but still this will be a looooong way from what one can do in HTML+CSS.

---

For completeness here is how to pass the `dvipsnames` option to `xcolor`:

```
latex_elements = {
    'passoptionstopackages': '\\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}',

    'preamble': r"""
\usepackage{colortbl}
% for Sphinx 1.5.x (1.6 ok, but 1.7 not):
\protected\def\sphinxstylethead {\cellcolor{Aquamarine}\textsf}
% better to use rather this with Sphinx 1.6 and mandatory if Sphinx 1.7:
% \protected\def\sphinxstyletheadfamily {\cellcolor{Aquamarine}\sffamily}
""",
}
```

Also, the `[named]` I mentioned above (`\rowcolor[named]{ForestGreen}`) is not needed with `xcolor` and I have not used it in `'preamble'` config here.

It *is* needed when only `color` package is used, but Sphinx uses `xcolor` if available.

Loading `colortbl` is not needed if one also passes option `table` to `xcolor`, and is perhaps better way in case the need for use of `xcolor`'s `\rowcolors` emerges at a later stage.

Merged cells from grid table cause arduous issues and Sphinx 1.6 will be much better than currently in this respect, however in current state of development, merged cells (multirow, multicolumn, or both) are set to simply ignore table colour commands.

Comment: Cool. Many thanks. That seems to be the best solution I've seen so far. I'll try it. I'm looking forward to see the cool features in Sphinx 1.6.

Comment: thanks, here one problem is that I could not use substitution for first row like for second row, because `\rowcolor` needs to be first in the row, and it would have ended up *inside*  the `\sphinxstylethead`. With  a template as currently on Sphinx master branch one could put the `\rowcolor` right there, before insertion of table header. Table templates will allow a few such rudimentary things, I don't want to raise too much hope ;-)

Comment: For anyone that came here from Google (like I did) to learn how to bold the header row for all tables (except tables >30 rows), add this to your preamble: `\protected\def\sphinxstyletheadfamily{\bfseries}` in newer versions of Sphinx.