# Sphinx latex class package option clash

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx and restructured text to generate a PDF with tables in it. I'd like to specify the `table` option to the `xcolor` package so I can use `\rowcolors` to achieve an alternating row color scheme.

Reviewing Sphinx documentation for adding packages, it appears I should use the `preamble` key in the `latex_elements` configuration to add my custom latex:

```latex
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{2}{blue!10}{white}
```

However, when I do that, I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor
```

Looking at the `.tex` file output by Sphinx, it appears the clash comes from `\usepackage[,numfigreset=2,mathnumfig]{sphinx}`, because the `sphinx.sty` class requires the `xcolor` package, which gets imported without any options.

I can get this to work by manually editing the `.tex` output and moving my `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` above the sphinx package import line, but there doesn't appear to be any way to achieve that via my `conf.py`.

Sphinx added [an `extrapackages` key](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html#latex-elements-confval) that places custom latex prior to the `hyperref` package import, but that is still after the sphinx package import.

I've also tried the `passoptionstopackages` key, which adds the latex `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}`, but this also doesn't work when it comes after the initial import of `xcolor`.

I think I have three main questions:

1. Is there another way to achieve an alternating row coloring scheme for tables in a PDF with Sphinx?
2. Does anyone know why the `extrapackages` key only places package import above `hyperref` and not others?
3. Is there a way to include custom latex or override Sphinx-generated latex above where `extrapackages` places it?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: 2: With very few exceptions, hyperref should be last.

Comment: Have you already tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988749/2777074 ?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://stackoverflow.com/a/42988749/2777074 seemed like a needless hack, but it's looking more and more like my only option. Something like that could work for manually defined tables, but won't work for a `csv-table`.